# Ruby Sort Array of Arrays by Child Element

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an "array of arrays" that has two values included at a time.

```
array = [[:tuesday, 0.25], [:monday, 1], [:thursday, 0.75]]
```

I'd like to use the number in the "child" array to sort the "parent" array in descending order. The result would look like:

```
array = [[:monday, 1], [:thursday, 0.75], [:tuesday, 0.25]]
```

I'm not too sure where to begin here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a block to the sort method like this:

```
array.sort { |a, b| b[1] <=> a[1] }
```

Answer (score 4):

I would be inclined to write

```
array.sort_by(&:last).reverse
```

Answer (score 3):

```
array = [['Tuesday',0.25],['Monday',1],['Thursday',0.75]]
p array.sort_by{|a| -a[1]}
# => [["Monday", 1], ["Thursday", 0.75], ["Tuesday", 0.25]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `sort` to return a new sorted array (saved as `new_array`).

```
new_array = array.sort{|x, y| y[1] <=> x[1]}
# => [["Monday", 1], ["Thursday", 0.75], ["Tuesday", 0.25]]
```

This keeps the original `array` unchanged.

```
array
# => [["Tuesday", 0.25], ["Monday", 1], ["Thursday", 0.75]]
```

Or you change the order of the original array by using `sort!`.

```
array.sort!{|x, y| y[1] <=> x[1]}
# => [["Monday", 1], ["Thursday", 0.75], ["Tuesday", 0.25]]

array
# => [["Monday", 1], ["Thursday", 0.75], ["Tuesday", 0.25]]
```